# UsersResource.MessagesResource.ListRequest returns only 100 messages

Tags: gmail-api

Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.UsersResource.MessagesResource.ListRequest has a property, MaxResults which is the "Maximum number of messages to return".  The default value is 100.  The following code allows me to change MaxResults:

```
var request = new UsersResource.MessagesResource.ListRequest(service, "me");
request.MaxResults = 5;
IList<Message> messages = request.Execute().Messages;
```

If I specify a value < 100, only that number of messages is returned.  However, if I specify a number > 100 only 100 are returned.  How can I have ALL messages returned?

Comment: Just a guess—you have to page through the results via multiple requests; 'maxresults' per page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try out the API explorer for [listing messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list), you can see that if you get 100 or more results, Google will page it for you so that you don't end up accidentally fetching thousand of results. To get the next page, simply include the `nextPageToken` you get from the first response in your next request:

**Request:**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages
```

**Response (Page 1):**

```
{
 "messages": [
    {
     "id": "15049b2405be054a",
     "threadId": "15049b2405be054a"
    }, . . .
  ],
 "nextPageToken": "07838313978415221418"
}
```

**Next request:**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?pageToken=07838313978415221418
```

**Response (Page 2):**

```
{
 "messages": [
    {
     "id": "14ffa7f009d50dd1",
     "threadId": "14ffa7f009d50dd1"
    }, ...
  ], ...
}
```

Just keep on doing this until there is no `nextPageToken` in the response,  and you will have fetched every result.

Comment: beautiful!  thanks for taking time to help.  and appreciate the link to API explorer for listing messages.

Comment: @Ben No problem :) Glad I could help!